# Updating Doctrine Collection

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I'm working on a survey project and I got 3 Entities, survey(umfrage), surveyQuestion(umfrageFrage) and surveyAnswer(umfrageAntwort).
Here are the entities(removed all unnecessary fields):

```
namespace Umfrage\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * Umfrage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="umfrage")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Umfrage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Fragen
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage", mappedBy="umfrage", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $fragen;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->fragen = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fragen
     *
     * @param \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage $fragen
     *
     * @return UmfrageFrage
     */
    public function setFragen($fragen)
    {
        $this->fragen = $fragen;
        return $this;
    }

     /** Get fragen
     *
     * @param \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage $fragen
     *
     * @return UmfrageFrage
     */
    public function getFragen() {
        return $this->fragen;
    }

    public function addFragen(Collection $fragen)
    {
        foreach ($fragen as $frage) {
            $frage->setUmfrage($this);            
            $this->fragen->add($frage);
        }
    }

    public function removeFragen(Collection $fragen)
    {
        foreach ($fragen as $frage) {
            $frage->setUmfrage(null);
            $this->fragen->removeElement($frage);
        }
    }
}
```

The Questions:

```
namespace Umfrage\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;


/**
* UmfrageFrage
*
* @ORM\Table(name="umfrage_frage")
* @ORM\Entity
 */
class UmfrageFrage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage", inversedBy="fragen")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="umfrage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $umfrage;

    /**
     * @var Antworten
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageAntwort", mappedBy="umfrageFrage", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $antworten;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->antworten = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set umfrage
     *
     * @param \Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage $umfrage
     *
     * @return UmfrageFrage
     */
    public function setUmfrage(\Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage $umfrage = null)
    {
        $this->umfrage = $umfrage;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get umfrage
     *
     * @return \Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage 
     */
    public function getUmfrage()
    {
        return $this->umfrage;
    }

    /**
     * Set antworten
     *
     * @param \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageAntwort $antworten
     *
     * @return UmfrageAntwort
     */
    public function setAntworten($antworten)
    {
        $this->antworten = $antworten;
        return $this;
    }

     /** Get antworten
     *
     * @param \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageAntwort $antworten
     *
     * @return UmfrageAntwort
     */
    public function getAntworten() {
        return $this->antworten;
    }

    public function addAntworten(Collection $antworten)
    {
        foreach ($antworten as $antwort) {
            $antwort->setUmfrageFrage($this);
            $this->antworten->add($antwort);
        }
    }

    public function removeAntworten(Collection $antworten)
    {
        foreach ($antworten as $antwort) {
            $this->antworten->removeElement($antwort);
        }
    }
}
```

The Answers:

```
namespace Umfrage\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * UmfrageAntwort
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="umfrage_antwort")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UmfrageAntwort
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage", inversedBy="antworten")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="umfrage_frage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $umfrageFrage;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set umfrageFrage
     *
     * @param \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage $umfrageFrage
     *
     * @return UmfrageFrage
     */
    public function setUmfrageFrage($umfrageFrage)
    {
        $this->umfrageFrage = $umfrageFrage;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get umfrageFrage
     *
     * @return \Umfrage\Entity\UmfrageFrage 
     */
    public function getUmfrageFrage()
    {
        return $this->umfrageFrage;
    }
}
```

The Controller action:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('umfrage', array('action'=>'add'));
    }

    $umfrage = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage', $id);

    $form = new UmfrageForm($this->getEntityManager());
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($this->getEntityManager(),'Umfrage\Entity\Umfrage'));

    $form->bind($umfrage);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($umfrage);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            // Redirect to overview
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('umfrage');
        }
    }
    $this->layout('layout/umfrage_backend');
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'id' => $id,
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```

And the view:

```
<?php
// module/Umfrage/view/umfrage/umfrage/edit.phtml:

use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug;
$title = 'Umfrage bearbeiten';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
                            'umfrage',
                            array(
                                'action' => 'edit',
                                'id'     => $this->id,
                            )
));
echo $this->ztbForm($form);
?>
```

Adding a Survey works fine, Deleting also, the Survey and its related Questions/Answers are removed from the DB. Only the Update actions doesn't work as expected. Survey and Questions are updated, but for the Answers I receive an Insert, instead of an Update, which results in duplicate entries in the DB. What's wrong with the Mapping(Code)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Post your View file as well

Comment: Ok, I added the view file, let me know, if any additional code is needed

Comment: ok, i think you have problem here 

 $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('umfrage', array('action'=>'add'));
    }
what happens is that when you post data, You are by some means unable to pass ID to Edit action, try doing some thing like this 
 $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
     $id=$request->getPost('id');
//this is not the optimized solution but i think it will work for now and you can modify it easily to solve your problem
}

Comment: The ID is ok, as I wrote, Survey and Questions are updated, only the third part with the Answers not. By now, I managed to get that to work, but in the DB, the Answers are still not updated. The old ones are set to null and the edited ones are still inserted. Any more ideas?

Comment: As i assumed you managed to come to Edit Action what i think is that you are some how are redirected to ADD Action so, looking at your View  which is fine and your routes which are fine too, the only thing that can be of doubt here is That you are redirected to ADD from your EDIT Action